# Initialization list on derived-derived class on C++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to implement the initialization list for the constructor of a derived-derived class. Please see base abstract class:

```
public:
Shape(char *Type = "Unknown")       
{
    this->Type = Type;
}

string getType() {return Type;}
```

Of course there is a derived `Rectangle` class, which is easy to implement:

```
public:
Rectangle(double Side1, double Side2) : Shape("Rectangle")
{
    this->Side1 = Side1;    
    this->Side2 = Side2;
}
```

Then I want to derive `Square` off `Rectangle` as a special case, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to include the supposed initialization list `Shape("Square")` on the next derived, `Square` class:

```
public:
Square(double Size) : Rectangle(Size, Size) { }
```

I can't use the colon operator again, can I. Any help, greatly appreciated.
My ultimate goal is to query on the cpp for the Type of both derived classes, which I instantiate as follows:

```
Shape *rectangle = new Rectangle(dSide1, dSide2);   
Shape *square = new Square(dSide1);
```

and retrieve thus:

```
cout << setw(t) << shape[i]->getType().data() ;
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `Type` member (storing `char*` is a bad idea anyway) and define `getType` as a virtual function: `virtual string getType() { return "Unknown"; }` - and repeat this for all your classes

Comment: @Martin. No, I can't do:    Square(double Size):Rectangle(Size, Size):Shape("Square){}...

Comment: @Ap31, +1  I just tried your recommended modification and of course it works like a charm,  thanks a lot. The char pointer implementation was our professor idea, so I'm not sure how it'll go down when he sees I changed his code :)

Comment: if that's what your professor told you to do, then perhaps you're restricted to the regular functions only (I'd wager virtual inheritance is out of the question too) - in this case, it looks like maybe he's preparing you for the introduction of virtual functions:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides of solutions in @n.m.'s answer, another way to do this, is to declare `Type` as a protected member, and initialize it directly in subclass' constructor:

```
class Shape {
public:
    Shape()
    {
        Type = "Unknown";
    }

    string getType() { return Type; }

protected:
    string Type;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(double Side1, double Side2)
    {
        this->Side1 = Side1;
        this->Side2 = Side2;
        Type = "Rectangle";
    }

protected:
    double Side1;
    double Side2;
};

class Square : public Rectangle
{
public:
    Square(double Size) : Rectangle(Size, Size) 
    { 
        Type = "Square";
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're not allowed to use virtual functions and virtual inheritance, this is the best solution to go with. Notice though that **assignment** in the constructor body is NOT an **initialization**. In fact, this will result in your `Type` pointer going through all the values in the inheritance path - e.g. when you're constructing a square, it will be "Unknown" first, then it'll change to "Rectangle", then to "Square" - some extra work, but it's much safer and makes some type logic sense

Comment: You are right, but `Type` can't be put in constructor's initial list either, is there a better idea?

Comment: Could you make `Type` a `const` member variable?

Comment: @MartinZhai no, that was the point - no need for better idea as this is actually how objects should behave - it's natural and exception-safe. Also technically speaking `vptr` goes through the same transformations for virtual functions to work. I'd even consider adding reverse process to destructor chain :D (just kidding)

Comment: @Jonas How does that help?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. Use virtual inheritance.

   ```
   class Shape {
   public:
     Shape(char *Type = "Unknown")       

   class Rectangle: public virtual Shape {
   public:
     Rectangle(double Side1, double Side2) : Shape("Rectangle")

   class Square: public Rectangle, public virtual Shape {
   public:
     Square(double Size) : Rectangle(Size, Size), Shape ("Square")
   ```
2. Add type argument to all constructors:

   ```
   class Shape {
   public:
     Shape(char *Type = "Unknown")       

   class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
     Rectangle(double Side1, double Side2, char *Type = "Rectangle") : Shape(Type)

   class Square: public Rectangle {
   public:
     Square(double Size, char *Type = "Square") : Rectangle(Size, Size, Type)
   ```

Having a type field (of whartever type) in your classes is not recommended though. If you need human readable tyoe name for display purposes, use a virtual function

```
class Shape {
  // this should be an abstract class
  public: virtual const char* type() = 0;

class Rectangle : public Shape {
  public: virtual const char* type() {
    return "Rectangle";
  }
```

Don't use such functions for other things, especially for determining your program logic.

Comment: I like the virtual inheritance one, but the design is flawed to begin with, this fix only makes it worse (because it makes it work)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer/comment. @Ap31, would you please point the flaws in my design? I am (obviously) just starting to learn this language and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, I've mentioned what I feel is the expected solution here in the comments to the question; What you're doing is mostly OK, but you don't have to store your class name as a member field - this is very redundant. Instead when you need polymorphic behavior, just use `virtual` functions. Also storing `char*` is a major bug magnet anyway as it's a non-owning pointer

Comment: @n.m. I tried your suggestion and, of course, it worked flawlessly. Many thanks for taking the time to reply and help me understand better this beautiful language.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't mean the virtual inheritance solution was bad, in fact it's probably better than exposing the `Type` member as an argument in all the `public` constructors, it just feels like a solution to a non-existent problem. And it's one more level of indirection, but who cares. It's pretty smart otherwise:)